# Swift - Convert values in array to doubles or floats

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift, double

I have an array with values which are strings (but all the strings are values like 1.0, 2.0, etc). I'm trying to convert those strings into doubles or floats so I can add them all together. How do I do this in swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.3.2 • Swift 3.1**

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    var doubleArray: [Double] {
        return flatMap{ Double($0) }
    }
    var floatArray: [Float] {
        return flatMap{ Float($0) }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let strNumbersArray = ["1.5","2.3","3.7","4.5"]   // ["1.5", "2.3", "3.7", "4.5"]
let doublesArray = strNumbersArray.doubleArray    // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
let floatsArray = strNumbersArray.floatArray      // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
let total = doublesArray.reduce(0, +)     // 12
let average = total / Double(doublesArray.count)  // 3
```

If you have an Array of Any? where you need to convert all strings from Optional Any to Double:

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Any? {
    var doubleArrayFromStrings: [Double] {
        return flatMap{ Double($0 as? String ?? "") }
    }
    var floatArrayFromStrings: [Float] {
        return flatMap{ Float($0 as? String ?? "") }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let strNumbersArray:[Any?] = ["1.5","2.3","3.7","4.5", nil]   // [{Some "1.5"}, {Some "2.3"}, {Some "3.7"}, {Some "4.5"}, nil]
let doublesArray = strNumbersArray.doubleArrayFromStrings    // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
let floatsArray = strNumbersArray.floatArrayFromStrings      // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
let total = doublesArray.reduce(0, +)     // 12
let average = total / Double(doublesArray.count)  // 3
```

Comment: I'm getting an error for that: `Type 'AnyObject?' does not conform to protocol 'StringType'`

Comment: This extension is for string arrays. Can you edit your question and add the original input source code?

Comment: That's weird. I'm downloading the array from parse and all of the objects in it are supposed to be strings: `var newarray = [object.objectForKey("times")]`

Comment: you need to cast as [String]

Comment: That gives another error: `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyObject?' to expected element type 'String'`

Comment: How to rewrite this extension for swift3? _ArrayType is renamed to _ArrayProtocol and it is made internal.

Comment: @JaganrajPalanivel updated to Swift 3.1 and Array of Any instead of AnyObject

Answer (score 7):

```
let x = ["1.0", "1.5", "2.0"]
print(x.map {Double($0)!})
```

Comment: `x.map {Double($0) ?? 0}` avoid **nil** while unwrapping ;)

Comment: Or use `compactMap`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.1**

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == String {
    var convertToDouble: [Double] {
        return compactMap{ Double($0) }
    }
    var convertToFloat: [Float] {
        return compactMap{ Float($0) }
    }
}
```

**Example How to Use**

```
let String_Array = ["1.5","2.3","3.7","4.5"]       // ["1.5", "2.3", "3.7", "4.5"]
let Double_Array = String_Array.convertToDouble    // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
let Float_Array = String_Array.convertToFloat.     // [1.5, 2.3, 3.7, 4.5]
```

**OR You can do this**

```
let numArray = ["1.0","2.0","3.0"]
let stringFromArray = numberArray[0]
let floatFromString = Float(stringFromArray)
let doubleFromString = Double(stringFromArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are sure that all of your array is string, you can directly cast your string into float or double.

```
let numberArray:Array = ["1.0","2.0","3.0"]
let stringFromArray = numberArray[0]
let floatFromString = Float(stringFromArray)
let doubleFromString = Double(stringFromArray)
```