# Extending typed array by conforming to a protocol in Swift 2

Tags: swift, generics, swift2, swift-extensions

I want to extend a typed array `Array<SomeType>` so that it conforms to a protocol `SomeProtocol`. Now I know you can extend a typed array like below:

```
extension Array where Element: SomeType { ... }
```

And you can also extend an object to conform to a protocol like so:

```
extension Array: SomeProtocol { ...  }
```

But I can't figure out what's the right syntax to have the typed array conform to a protocol, something like:

```
extension (Array where Element: SomeType): SomeProtocol { ... }
```

Any Swift 2 experts know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at the StringType protocol at this answer to extend array of strings http://stackoverflow.com/a/33862452/2303865

Comment: extension of type 'Array' with constraints cannot have an inheritance clause. there is no logic. can you provide us some useful example?

Comment: @JamesHu Have you had a time to look at and give feedback to our answers below?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't apply a lot of logic to conformance. It either does or does not conform. You can however apply a little bit of logic to extensions. The code below makes it easy to set specific implementations of conformance. Which is the important part.

This is used as a typed constraint later.

```
class SomeType { }
```

This is your protocol

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

    func foo()

}
```

This is an extension of the protocol. The implementation of `foo()` in an extension of `SomeProtocol` creates a default.

```
extension SomeProtocol {

    func foo() {
        print("general")
    }
}
```

Now `Array` conforms to `SomeProtocol` using the default implementation of `foo()`. All arrays will now have `foo()` as a method, which is not super elegant. But it doesn't do anything, so it's not hurting anyone.

```
extension Array : SomeProtocol {}
```

Now the cool stuff:
If we create an extension to `Array` with a type constraint for `Element` we can override the default implementation of `foo()`

```
extension Array where Element : SomeType {
    func foo() {
        print("specific")
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
let arrayOfInt = [1,2,3]
arrayOfInt.foo() // prints "general"

let arrayOfSome = [SomeType()]
arrayOfSome.foo() // prints "specific"
```

Answer (score 5):

In more recent versions of Swift it is possible to write:

`extension Array: SomeProtocol where Element == SomeType { ... }`

Unsure in which version of Swift this became possible, but the following works in Swift 4.1

```
class SomeType { }

protocol SomeProtocol {
    func foo()
}

extension Array: SomeProtocol where Element == SomeType {
    func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }
}

let arrayOfSome = [SomeType()]
arrayOfSome.foo() // prints "foo"

let arrayOfInt = [1,2,3]
arrayOfInt.foo() // Will not compile: '[Int]' is not convertible to 'Array<SomeType>'
```

(I am aware that the question specifically asks for Swift 2, but I am adding this for reference)

Comment: I looked it up, it's called [conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md) and part of Swift since version 4.2 according to this link.

Answer (score 2):

I've been fiddling around some with this myself, and there are some ways to somewhat mimic the behaviour you're looking for.

---

**Approach #1**

Define a protocol `SomeType` to act as the type constraint for the types that you wish to be covered by your `Array<SomeType>` extension for `SomeProtocol`; where the latter contains blueprints for some neat methods that you wish to extend `Array`.

```
protocol SomeType {
    var intValue: Int { get }
    init(_ value: Int)
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

extension Int : SomeType { var intValue: Int { return self } }
extension Double : SomeType { var intValue: Int { return Int(self) } }
    /* Let's not extend 'Float' for now
extension Float : MyTypes { var intValue: Int { return Int(self) } } */

protocol SomeProtocol {
    func foo<T: SomeType>(a: [T]) -> Int?
}
```

Now, you can extend `Array` to `SomeProtocol`, and by using the `is` keyword, you can assert that the you generic `T` (constrained by `SomeType`) and elements of `Self` are of the same type by using the `is` keyword, that, if true, is followed by explicit casting:

```
extension Array : SomeProtocol {
    func foo<T: SomeType>(a: [T]) -> Int? {
        /* [T] is Self? proceed, otherwise return nil */
        if let b = self.first {
            if b is T && self.count == a.count {
                var myMultSum: T = T(0)

                for (i, sElem) in self.enumerate() {
                    myMultSum += (sElem as! T) * a[i]
                }
                return myMultSum.intValue
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

We've now extended `Array` with elements of `SomeType` with the function `foo(...)` blueprinted in the protocol `SomeProtocol`.

```
/* Tests */
let arr1d : [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let arr2d : [Double] = [-3.0, -2.0, 1.0]

let arr1f : [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let arr2f : [Float] = [-3.0, -2.0, 1.0]

func bar<U: SomeType> (arr1: [U], _ arr2: [U]) -> Int? {
    return arr1.foo(arr2)
}
let myInt1d = bar(arr1d, arr2d) // -4, OK

let myInt1f = bar(arr1f, arr2f)
    /* Compile time error: "Cannot convert value of type '[Float]'
       to expected argument type '[_]'"                            */
```

Ok! We expected the final compile time error here as 'Float' does not conform to `SomeType` protocol.

---

**Approach #2**

Now for another approach: I've based the generics that follow on [this excellent post by Milen Dzhumerov](http://milen.me/writings/swift-generic-protocols/), here adapted for an array and with some different extension method examples.

For this example, we're implementing a "generic" protocol extension for `Array`:s of type `Double` or `Float`, represented by the type constraint protocol `SomeType`

```
protocol SomeType {
    init(_ value: Int)
    init(_ value: Double)
    init(_ value: Float)
    func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}

extension Double: SomeType {}
extension Float: SomeType {}

protocol GenericProtocol {
    typealias AbstractType : SequenceType
    func repeatNumberNumberManyTimes(arg: Int) -> AbstractType
    func removeRandomElement(arg: AbstractType) -> AbstractType
    func countNumberOf42s(arg: AbstractType) -> Int

}
```

Forward the `GenericProtocol` to `AbstractType` (which, here, conforms to `SequenceType`) using a structure, and implement the protocol blueprints in the latter:

```
struct SomeArrayProtocol<T: SequenceType> : GenericProtocol {
    private let _repeatNumberNumberManyTimes : (Int) -> T
    private let _removeRandomElement : (T) -> T
    private let _countNumberOf42s : (T) -> Int

    init<P : GenericProtocol where P.AbstractType == T>(_ dep : P) {
        _repeatNumberNumberManyTimes = dep.repeatNumberNumberManyTimes
        _removeRandomElement = dep.removeRandomElement
        _countNumberOf42s = dep.countNumberOf42s
    }

    func repeatNumberNumberManyTimes(arg: Int) -> T {
        return _repeatNumberNumberManyTimes(arg)
    }

    func removeRandomElement(arg: T) -> T {
        return _removeRandomElement(arg)
    }

    func countNumberOf42s(arg: T) -> Int {
        return _countNumberOf42s(arg)
    }
}
```

Implement the actual methods for the `GenericProtocol` blueprints in another structure, where the generic is now constrained to `SomeType` type constraint (protocol). Note that it's this part that mimics your wished fir (but straightforwardly unattainable) form `extension (Array where Element: SomeType): SomeProtocol { ... }`:

```
struct SomeArrayGenericExtensions<T: SomeType> : GenericProtocol {
    typealias AbstractType = Array<T>
    func repeatNumberNumberManyTimes(arg: Int) -> [T] {
        return Array<T>(count: arg, repeatedValue: T(arg))
    }
    func removeRandomElement(arg: [T]) -> [T] {
        var output = [T]()
        let randElemRemoved = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(arg.count-1)))
        for (i,element) in arg.enumerate() {
            if i != randElemRemoved {
                output.append(element)
            }
        }
        return output
    }
    func countNumberOf42s(arg: [T]) -> Int {
        var output = 0
        for element in arg {
            if element == T(42) {
                output++
            }
        }
        return output
    }
}
```

Finally, some tests:

```
let myGenericExtensionUsedForDouble : SomeArrayProtocol<Array<Double>> = SomeArrayProtocol(SomeArrayGenericExtensions())
let myGenericExtensionUsedForFloat : SomeArrayProtocol<Array<Float>> = SomeArrayProtocol(SomeArrayGenericExtensions())
// let myGenericExtensionUsedForInt : SomeArrayProtocol<Array<Int>> = SomeArrayProtocol(SomeArrayGenericExtensions()) // Error! Int not SomeType, OK!

var myDoubleArr = [10.1, 42, 15.8, 42.0, 88.3]
let my10EntriesOfTenDoubleArr = myGenericExtensionUsedForDouble.repeatNumberNumberManyTimes(10) // ten 10:s
let myFloatArr : Array<Float> = [1.3, 5, 8.8, 13.0, 28, 42.0, 42.002]
let myIntArr = [1, 2, 3]

let a = myGenericExtensionUsedForDouble.countNumberOf42s(myDoubleArr) // 2
let b = myGenericExtensionUsedForFloat.countNumberOf42s(myFloatArr) // 1

myDoubleArr = myGenericExtensionUsedForDouble.removeRandomElement(myDoubleArr) // [10.1, 15.8, 42.0, 88.3]
```

---

I somewhat unsure whether Approach 2 above actually has some practical applications for arrays or not (in Milans coverage he treats non-sequence types, perhaps more useful); it's quite a bit of work for not so much extra bang for the buck. However, it can be an instructive, and quite entertaining exercise :)