# How to add a type constraint (protocol conformance) for a generic Array parameter of a function (and not for its Generator.Element)

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

**Question background**

I have a question based on my own attempt to yield a satisfactory workaround for the behaviour wanted by the OP of the following thread:

- [Extending typed array by conforming to a protocol in Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467606/extending-typed-array-by-conforming-to-a-protocol-in-swift-2/34468382#34468382)

The subject is (like a few others here at SO...) attempting to mimic generic array extensions that conform to some protocol. There was a recent similar question regarding this subject in this thread:

- [extend generic Array<T> to adopt protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475597/extend-generic-arrayt-to-adopt-protocol/34475721)

---

**Question**

My question cover the next step. Lets say we manage to implement a somewhat generic extension to `Array`, conforming to some protocol blueprints, say `MyProtocol`. Hence, from now on, assume that `Array` instances, for some types of `Generator.Element` (say, for `MyTypes`), are now extended and conforms to `MyProtocol`.

Then, for a function taking a generic `Array` (or, specifically, say `<U: _ArrayType ...`, or possibly `RangeReplaceableCollectionType ...` or `SequenceType ...`) type) as argument, *is there any way to add a type constraint to the actual generic array* (`U`), and not just to its `Generator.Element` type? (so not `... where Generator.Element.Type == SomeTypeConstraint`).

***Example***

I'll try to show my question "in action" to help specify what I'm actually asking. Note that this is the most MWE I've been able to construct for this purpose, my apologies if it's possibly a bit hefty.

Protocols (protocol `MyTypes` for use as type + protocol `MyProtocol` used for array extension):

```
/* Used as type constraint for Generator.Element */
protocol MyTypes {
    var intValue: Int { get }
    init(_ value: Int)
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func +=(inout lhs: Self, rhs: Self)
}

extension Int : MyTypes { var intValue: Int { return self } }
extension Double : MyTypes { var intValue: Int { return Int(self) } }
/* Let's not extend 'Float' for now
   extension Float : MyTypes { var intValue: Int { return Int(self) } } */

/* Used as extension to Array : blueprints for extension method
   to Array where Generator.Element: are constrainted to MyTypes */
protocol MyProtocol {
    //typealias T
    func foo<T: MyTypes>(a: [T]) -> Int?
}
```

Extension of `Array` by `MyProtocol`; implementation of blue-printed method:

```
extension Array : MyProtocol {
    func foo<T: MyTypes>(a: [T]) -> Int? {
        /* [T] is Self? proceed, otherwise return nil */
        if let b = self.first {
            if b is T && self.count == a.count {
                var myMultSum: T = T(0)

                for (i, sElem) in self.enumerate() {
                    myMultSum += (sElem as! T) * a[i]
                }
                return myMultSum.intValue
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Some tests where we, for a function, constrain the `Generator.Element` of the `Array` arguments to `MyTypes`, hence somewhat *implicitly* asserting that only arrays conforming to `MyProtocol` can use the function:

```
/* Tests */
let arr1d : [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let arr2d : [Double] = [-3.0, -2.0, 1.0]

let arr1f : [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
let arr2f : [Float] = [-3.0, -2.0, 1.0]

func bar1<U: MyTypes> (arr1: [U], _ arr2: [U]) -> Int? {
    return arr1.foo(arr2)
}
let myInt1d = bar1(arr1d, arr2d) // -4, OK

//let myInt1f = bar1(arr1f, arr2f)
    /* Error: Cannot convert value of type '[Float]'
       to expected argument type '[_]'

  OK! Expected as 'Float' does not conform to MyTypes protocol */
```

We've now arrived to the core of my question, something I haven't been able to construct myself: Is there any possible way to *explicitly* constrain an array generic, say `U`, to `MyProtocol` (for which `Array` for some `Generator.Elements` have been constrained)? I would like to do something along the lines

```
func bar2<T: MyTypes, U: protocol<MyProtocol, _ArrayType> where U.Generator.Element == T> (arr1: U, _ arr2: U) -> Int? {

    // OK, type 'U' behaves as an array type with elements 'T' (==MyTypes)
    var a = arr1
    var b = arr2
    a.append(T(0))
    b.append(T(0))

    return a.foo(b)
        /* Error: Cannot convert value of type 'U'
           to expected argument type '[_]'          */
}
let myInt2 = bar2(arr1d, arr2d)
```

- Is this possible, perhaps in a different manner?

---

(Feel free to edit this question to improve it, I'm not very well versed at the process of asking, and the best practice for, questions here at SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix my *"do something along the lines"* proposal work, by:

- Switching from `<U: SequenceType ...` to `<U: _ArrayType ...` (see edit history),
- For calling my generic array extension with an generic array (generic `U`), explicitly initialize an array in the call, explicitly telling reciever that the caller argument (of generic type `U`) is of type `Array` (using `Array(...)` initializer).

Hence, we *can* add a type constraint (protocol conformance) for a generic array parameter of a function, using the generic array extension as described in the question, followed by the following approach for protocol conformance:

```
func bar2<T: MyTypes, U: protocol<MyProtocol, _ArrayType> where U.Generator.Element == T> (arr1: U, _ arr2: U) -> Int? {

    // OK, type U behaves as array type with elements T (=MyTypes)
    var a = arr1
    var b = arr2
    a.append(T(2)) // add 2*7 to multsum
    b.append(T(7))

    return a.foo(Array(b))
        /* Ok! */
}
let myInt2 = bar2(arr1d, arr2d) // -4+2*7 = 10, OK
```